# Ansible npm module doesn't create node_modules directory

Tags: ansible

I wrote a playbook with the `npm:` Ansible module, and I expected to see a `node_modules` directory when I execute it. There is, however, no such directory created.

```
  - name: install packages based on package.json
    npm:
      path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/project_dir/"
    tags: npm
```

Note that `project_dir/package.json` exists. When I execute `npm install` in this directory, it creates a `node_modules` folder.

Is Ansible's npm module written correctly, based on my assumption that the behavior should be to create the node_modules directory upon running this npm module?

EDIT: the only dependencies in the package.json file are `devDependencies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time this question was asked it turned out that the `npm` version was too old to understand the [`npm list --json --long`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/language/npm.py#L181) that the module uses to decide if it needs to take any action.

Try one of two things:

1. Upgrade `npm` to be a modern version
2. Re-run `ansible-playbook -vv` to attempt to get more information that might confirm or deny the theory

If you do experience that your `npm` is too old, it would be awesome if you would [file an issue with ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) about that problem